# Substring of itself

Tags: c++, string, exception, substring

When I write

```
string mystring("blabbing;hyfcvfddffc");
// mystring can be modified during application process
int tokemFrom = mystring.find(';');
mystring = mystring.substr((tokenFrom + 1));
```

I have learned that this syntax can be unsafe when my string is empty, or the `;` is not found, throwing an exception. I rewrote the code avoid this problem as:

```
string mystring("blabbing;hyfcvfddffc");
// mystring can be modified during application process
int tokenFrom = mystring.find(';');
string temp = mystring.substr((tokenFrom + 1));
mystring = temp;
```

Is there a simpler way to make sure that my code is safe?

Comment: Check what value the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function actually returns?

Comment: I dont see how your second version is any safer than the first. If you want to improve it you have to check the return value, as suggested by Joachim.

Comment: You have to check `tokenFrom != string::npos` before doing `substr` . Also it should have type `auto` (or `string::size_type`), not `int`.

Comment: Will do that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of everything in the string after the `;` Then you can use [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) instead of assigning to a substring of itself.

```
std::string::size_type pos;
std::string foo("blabbing;hyfcvfddffc");
pos = foo.find(";");
foo.erase(pos == std::string::npos ? foo.size() : pos);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db09b03034bc809f)</kbd>

So we get the position of the `;` and then in `erase` is the position is equal to `std::string::npos` which signals it was not found then we tell erase to start erasing from the end of the string which will do nothing.  Otherwise it will erase from the position of the `;`.

Comment: I guess you should use `std::string::size_type` instead of `std::size_t`.

Comment: @Lingxi Updated to make it more portable.